# How do I add a numbered suffix at the end of my files using split on Linux BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ubuntu

I'm using the split command in a Macbook and instead of getting numbers, I'm getting files such as output_aa, output_ab, output_ac, and what I need is output_1 , output_2, output_3, and so on.

Here's the code I'm using, it's on a .txt of a book (Harry Potter) and I'm trying to split it between chapters, however I need my endfiles to have the number corresponding to its chapter.
**split -p Chapter hp.txt hp_cap_**

Comment: Did you read [the documentation of split](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html)? Look at `-d`

Comment: BTW, split is not part of bash, and its behavior is exactly the same whether you use it from bash or any other shell, or even use it from no shell at all (like invoking with the Python `subprocess` module with `shell=False`). Linux and MacOS have completely different versions of `split`, so tagging both operating systems makes your question ambiguous.

Comment: (Indeed, it's confusing that you say "on Linux" in the title and specify Ubuntu, but then also specify "on a macbook" and tag macos as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you want to do with the macos version of the split command. Install coreutils

```
frank in ~
brew install coreutils
```

and use gsplit with the -d option

```
frank in ~ 
$ gsplit --help | grep -- "-d"
  -d                      use numeric suffixes starting at 0, not alphabetic
      --numeric-suffixes[=FROM]  same as -d, but allow setting the start value
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -d option

```
-d  use numeric suffixes starting at 0, not alphabetic
```

Example:

```
split -d hp.txt hp_cap_
```

Output:

```
hp_cap_00
hp_cap_01
hp_cap_02
```

Comment: I tried it but i got this error "split: illegal option -- d"

Comment: If you run "man split" do you have "-d" option ? 
Online man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html

Comment: No, the only options i have are split [-a suffix_length] [-b byte_count[k|m]] [-l line_count]
           [-p pattern] [file [name]]

Comment: It seems your split doesn't contain all features of the Linux split. 
1. You can run the command in some Linux environment or Docker image with Linux. 
2. After producing "output_aa, output_ab..."  you can rename the files. Check this article:
https://eikhart.com/blog/autosplit-csv